# C Linked List Add Item at the End

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a program that adds a node at the end of an existing linked list.
The problem is that it doesn't seem to assign to the variable `nr` of `struct node` of the last element of the linked list the hard coded value `7`.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int nr;
    struct node *next;
};

void addNodes(struct node **head, int n);
void displayList(struct node *head);
void addItemLast(struct node *head);

int main() {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    int n;

    printf("Introduceti numarul de noduri: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    addNodes(&head, n);
    displayList(head);
    addItemLast(head);
    displayList(head);

    return 0;
}

void addNodes(struct node **head, int n) {
    *head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current = *head;

    printf("\nIntroduceti %d noduri:\n", n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Element %d = ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &(current -> nr));

        current->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = NULL;
}

void displayList(struct node *head) {
    struct node *current = head;
    int i = 1;

    printf("\nElementele introduse sunt:\n");
    while(current->next != NULL) {
        printf("Elementul %d = %d\n", i, current->nr);

        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void addItemLast(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp = head, *last;
    last = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(last == NULL) {
        printf("\nMemory cannot be allocated!\n");
    } else {
        last->nr = 7;
        last->next = NULL;

        while(1) {
            if(temp->next == NULL) {
                temp->next = last;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The last function, `addItemLast()`, doesn't work as expected.

This is the output:

```
Introduceti numarul de noduri: 3

Introduceti 3 noduri:
Element 1 = 1
Element 2 = 2
Element 3 = 3

Elementele introduse sunt:
Elementul 1 = 1
Elementul 2 = 2
Elementul 3 = 3
```

After the function with the problem runs, I get this output:

```
Elementele introduse sunt:
Elementul 1 = 1
Elementul 2 = 2
Elementul 3 = 3
Elementul 4 = 13383248
```

Element 4 does not contain the hard coded value `7`, but instead has a garbage value and I can't figure out why.

Comment: It is because you are not displaying last node    `while(current->next != NULL)` should be  `while(current != NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implemenation of `addNodes` is incorrect, suppose I enter `n = 2` , 3 nodes are created but only twice `scanf` function  is called, so as result you have garbage value in some node (`nr` is not set).

Reimplement it (it works if `addItemLast` function is properly implemented) :

```
void addNodes(struct node **head, int n){
    printf("\nIntroduceti %d noduri:\n", n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        struct node* last = addItemLast(*head);
        if (*head == NULL)
            *head = last;

        printf("Element %d = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &(last -> nr));
    }
}
```

---

You need to change `addItemLast` to handle case when you want to call this function but `head` is `NULL` (without testing this case your program crashes while calling `addItemLast` for empty List):

```
struct node* addItemLast(struct node *head){
    struct node *temp = head, *last;

    last = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (head == NULL)  // <---------
    {
        last->nr = 7;
        last->next = NULL;
        return last;
    }

    if(last == NULL){
        printf("\nMemory cannot be allocated!\n");
    }else{
        last->nr = 7;
        last->next = NULL;

        while(1){
            if(temp->next == NULL){
                temp->next = last;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

---

and finally function to display list should be:

```
   void displayList(struct node *head){
        struct node *current = head;
        int i = 1;

        printf("\nElementele introduse sunt:\n");
        while(current != NULL){  // <---------
            printf("Elementul %d = %d\n", i, current->nr);

            current = current->next;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to check if `current->next != NULL` when accessing the element of `current`.

Change your while loop to:

```
while(current != NULL){
        printf("Elementul %d = %d\n", i, current->nr);

        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }
```